# ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: maven, dependencies, jwt

I am following this [article](http://massimilianosciacco.com/spring-security-jwt-authentication) to implement token authentication. Nimbus was added as a dependency in my pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>4.16.2</version>
</dependency>
```

All the JWT stuff was recognized except ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet. Based on this  [link](http://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/2.21/com/nimbusds/jwt/class-use/ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet.html), it should be under `com.nimbusds.jwt.ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet`. Why can't it be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Connect2id Support, "The JWT classes were refactored in version 4.0, and it now uses an immutable JWT object - JWTClaimsSet."

Since I am using the latest version of Nimbus which is 4.16.2, I had to replace all `ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet` with `JWTClaimsSet` and it works.